# How to display a preview of an Image in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, imagemagick

I load an image to qt using Imagemagick and then
I have several widgets that perform various actions to an image(blur, black and white, levels etc). There is an image preview that I show to the end user every time the image is manipulated.

The problem I have is that if for example I apply some blur effects(using horizontalSlider), I wont be able to remove it as the object is already manipulated.

Here is my connection to the function

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider_blur, SIGNAL(actionTriggered(int)), this, SLOT(blur(double,int)));
```

and here is how I apply effects and update the label to display my image

```
void MainWindow::blur(double factor, int pixels)
{
    image.blur(pixels,factor);
    image.write(&blob);
    imgData = ((char*)(blob.data()));
    pixmap.loadFromData(imgData, "XPM");
    ui->label->setPixmap( pixmap );
}
```

Will it be good idea to copy the image object every time I apply effects?
if so, how do I do that?

What are the best practice to manipulate the image and display its preview dynamically?

come on Qt experts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should keep a line of your image states (after a new effect is applied you should create a new state - a copy of an image). So you can simply roll back if you need. A List structure will be good for this purpose. Using such approach you can not only roll back, but fully implement undo-redo system.

When you want to apply a new effect to your image - make a new copy and work with it. If the effect is created put it in a state list, if canceled - remove. To copy a QImage use it's copy method.

To display a preview simply resize an image and display it.

PS: it's not a good idea to apply an effect directly to a preview because the result can differ from the final result (when effect is applied to unscaled image).

**EDIT:**
Also i think it is possible to optimize saving states for small effects, applied to a part of your image (such as brush stroke). In such situation really you need to save only the part of image, where to stroke has been applied. For example you can create something as a          `StateManager` which will know how to do undo/redo, `State` class (basic class for states) and some State subclasses to implement your needs: `CompleteState : State` for saving an effect applied to all the image, and `PartState : State` for an effect applied to a part.

Comment: Great advnice Andrew but i said Im using sliders. Lets assume a scenario. I load an image and Im applying blur effect through slider by pulling the slider from 0 to 50 what if then I decide 50 is too much and I want to take it back to 25 ? what will i do with the image object ? Thank you!

Comment: Look, when you are going to create a new effect you make a copy of your image. So exactly you have two copies of your image (original and a copy). On each step of a slider you should recreate or update the copy from the last state (original image) and apply an effect to it (copy). I think that's the only way because to apply the effect correctly you should always have the clear image.